# Am I out of luck trying to communicate with this transmitter?

Tags: networking

There are a lot of specifics in this particular case so I will include the ones I think are important, and provide more if requested...

I'm very new to Ubuntu/unix in general and am trying to communicate with a Micro Motion 2500 transmitter using Modbus RTU RS-485 protocol, I have a USB to RS-485 converter straight to the terminal block of the transmitter. (I can't find a color code on the cable so I have been testing different connections as I go).

Right now I am just trying to establish any sort of connection to the device using a simple Python script, and minimalmodbus module as well.

```
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB1', 1) """ port 
name, slave address """

x = instrument.read_register(0, 1) """ register number, decimal number 
"""

print(x)
```

My question is, all the drivers/software provided for this transmitter is Windows-exclusive, is it impossible to communicate with this device w/o a Windows OS? It would save me tons of time to know this simple fact.

After running `mesg -w`:

There is > 100000 characters, so it can't be posted, sorry

`lsusb`:

`\Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1770:ff00

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Most USB modbus adapters is simply a serial port. USB serial ports tends to work on Linux. If it appears as a device (say ttyUSB1) it almost certainly works. If you want a better answer, unplug the device, run `dmesg -w` in a terminal, and plug in the device, and [edit] your question with the content that appeared when you plugged in the device.

Comment: @vidarlo The USB-RS485 does not appear as a USB device because there isn't a signal on the other end (I am guessing), I've verified the USB port with other USB devices. When I run `dmesg -w` I get a few hundred lines of code, and when I plug the device in again it's the same (there could be differences but the text is way too long)... I should reiterate that this is a cable hardwired into a transmitter with RS485 conversion in between, so I assume there needs to be comm on both ends, using `lsusb` does not return the device

Comment: Serial connections are connectionless, so it does **not** matter if there's wires in the other end. If you won't give us the information from dmesg (it should be tens of lines, not hundreds; the relevant lines is the ones that appear after you insert the device), there is **no** way we can help you.

Comment: And additionally, where does `/dev/ttyUSB1` come from if it does not appear as a device?

Comment: @vidarlo I am using that because other devices plugged into a specific USB port ID as `/dev/ttyUSB1`

Comment: Ok. Can you include the output of `lsusb` and tell us the make and model of the device? Btw - the first serial device will be ttyUSB0, the second ttyUSB1 and so on. It's not based on which port it is connected to afaik.

Comment: @vidarlo I see! Ok so the output of `lsusb` is in OP. Device is Emerson Micro Motion 2500 Transmitter

Comment: Btw, I believe you're misunderstanding. Run `dmesg -w` with the device not plugged in. Plug in the device. Paste the **new** text that appears. This should be quite few lines. If you want you can clear the messages with `sudo dmesg -C` before running dmesg again after plugging in.

Comment: I understood the original advice, maybe it was large because I tried it multiple times. I cleared the messages and ran `dmesg -w` again, but there seems to be a process running in terminal and it won't return anything

Comment: If you cleared the message buffer there's nothing to output. But some text should appear when you plug in your usb device. You can exit it with Ctrl+C

Comment: Ok inserted USB, nothing.

Comment: the problem must be within the cable.

Comment: Your USB to rs-485 adapter seems to be not working. When you plug it in your computer, it should be listed with `lsusb`, it should produce some lines in `dmesg` and if all goes well, il will appear in /dev as ttyUSB? It does not have to be connected to anything else.

Comment: @Jean-Marie You're very right, I have a new USB to RS485 and `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` shows it. Now to talk with the transmitter.